# php form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a website using Wordpress on WAMP server.

I use BlankSlate theme and used Elementor plugin to design.

I completed all the pages, and now the Contact Us form has to be inserted.

The plugin forms did not work for me while sending emails, and my client did not like the layout. So I copied HTML code from a another website and did the CSS part without a plugin.

Now that the designing part is over, in order to send emails, I am trying to implement the PHP.

Elementor did not accept any form PHP. So I decided to code this page completely. I created a child theme and started editing `Page.php`, renaming it to `Page-contact-us.php`.

The page design is perfect, but sending emails is neither working through PHP nor through the plugin.

**Apart from the code and design, am I missing any mail setup or configuration?**

Here's the code:

```
    <?php 
    $name=$_POST['name'];`enter code here`
    $email=$_POST['email']; 
    $phone=$_POST['phone']; 
    $company=$_POST['company'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg'];
    $to='sumaiya.shabnam@gmail.com';
    $subject='Contact form';
    $message= "Name:" 
   .$name."\n"."Phone:".$phone."\n"."From:".$company."\n"."Wrote the 
    following:"."\n\n".$msg;
    $headers ="MIME-Version:1.0"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8"."\r\n";
    $headers="From: ".$email;
    ?>

    <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
    <h4>And we will get back to you. </h4>
    <fieldset>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" 
    required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <input name = "email" name placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" 
    tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <input name="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number " type="tel" 
    tabindex="3"  required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Your current company" type="text" tabindex="4" 
     required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...." tabindex="5" 
    required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data- 
    submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
     <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     { 
     if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
     {
         echo "Thanks for the email; We will get back to you shortly!";
     }
        else { echo "Failed to send; Please try again";}
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: use this if else block of code at the  top of form tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my problem is that the elements that the passed through the form to the php like name, email, phone are the generic terms which wordpress will not allow or it can be said those elements are already used in-built in wordpress. So I changed the elements name to contact_name, contact_email, contact_phone and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are good resources available on how to code contact forms.  There are a number of things you could do to improve what you have so far.  1) Use wordpress wp_mail to send the mail

```
$success = wp_mail( string|array $to, string $subject, string $message, string|array $headers = '', string|array $attachments = array() )
```

2) As Mohit suggested, you should also have some if then else code.  Something like:

if (form_submitted_securely_and_from_this_site) then {
    wp_mail,
    display success or failure message
}
else show contact form

3) For "form_submitted_securely_and_from_this_site" - I'd suggest adding some code to be sure that any post submissions actually come from your website, from that page.   There are a number of pages on the web about how to code secure forms.

4) Also I suggest having sanitisation and validation on the fields submitted.  Wordpress has functions to help with that.  See https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data.

Comment: Thanks so much. however, always when I use the contact form, after submission, it says Page not found, which means it is running the 404.php instead of the mail.php. I tried different php codes. still not working. I mean it is not even showing any error. it is directly calling the 404.php page.

Comment: Googling "wordpress form 404" leads me to think that most likely the form is using a wordpress reserved word.  Make sure all your field names are unique to your form and try again.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685020/wordpress-form-submission-and-the-404-error-page and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11749/why-when-i-submit-a-form-in-wordpress-it-loads-a-404-page-though-url-is-correct

Answer (score 0):

Your `textarea` element ( which has `placeholder="Type your message here...."`) and the `input` element before it (having `placeholder="Your current company"`) don't have `name` attributes. Judging from the code at the top of the page these names should be "company" and "msg". Without those `name` attributes your form won't work, since their values won't be transmitted so that `$company=$_POST['company'];` and `$msg=$_POST['msg'];` won't be defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I found that already and included.